# How can I modify document classes, or do I have to make my own?

Tags: document-classes

I am a raw beginner at Latex, so this is a newbie question.

I tried to write a letter using the document class "letter" in latex, but it is formatted completely differently than the way I write letters. For example, I put the date first, not the sender address. But the date is apparently inserted automatically by the class, so there is no way to modify it that I can see.

What is the procedure to deal with problems like this? Do I write my own version of the letter class? Is that easy to do, or am I better off just writing a plain text document and not using specialized classes like "letter"?

Comment: I would use some other class. See here for a number of options: https://ctan.org/topic/letter (I recommend to use something that looks as if it is actively maintained, so check the dates).

Comment: You can probably use minimal class and add things like \usepackage{geometry} to set the margins, or  other packages to define any macros you might need.